# SIGSEGV in background thread NSRunLoop runMode:beforeDate:

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, segmentation-fault, nsrunloop

I am using background threads with following pattern:

```
// Defined in .h-file as ivar
BOOL backgroundThreadIsAlive;


// .m file
static NSThread *backgroundThread = nil;

- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {       
        if (backgroundThread == nil)
        {
            backgroundThreadIsAlive = YES;
            backgroundThread = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self selector:@selector(threadMain:) object:nil];
            [backgroundThread start];
        }
    }

    return self;
}


- (void)threadMain:(id)data
{
    NSRunLoop *runloop = [NSRunLoop currentRunLoop];
    [runloop addPort:[NSMachPort port] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

    while (backgroundThreadIsAlive)
    {
        [runloop runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
    }
}
```

My application sometimes crash with SIGSEGV in the line

```
[runloop runMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode beforeDate:[NSDate distantFuture]];
```

I am using ARC. The crash is not reproducible. Just found it, when diving into testflight and saw this is the most often crash I got. It seems to appear independently from iOS version (I support iOS5+) and device type.

- May someone have a hint for me, what I do wrong?
- Is there a better solution doing background-threads? (maybe using GCD)
- Is there a way to reproduce those issues?

Thank you for your time and guidiance. :)

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was the cause here, or did you avoid it in some way?

Comment: Hey Scott, I found out, that it has not to do with the code running here. The stack trace in the code later showed up INTERNAL changes of a textfield. Problem was, that I modified the text field in non-ui-thread, but the modifying code did not took place in the stak trace. So it's a guess game, which line produces the problem, when using this construct.

Comment: Thanks - that's helpful information all the same.

Comment: Hey Scott, today I sent a DTS request to Apple regarding another problem similar to this. I hope they'll help me to read the crash logs and get better information out of this. I'll keep you up to date, if they send me good hints.

Comment: Thanks! Eagerly awaiting any tips :)